# How to font preloading in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

How to integrate this line in TYPO3

I tried

`<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">`

```
page.includeCSS {
    file1 = https://fonts.gstatic.com
    file1.external = 1
    file1.preconnect = 1 
}
```

but file1.preconnect not working correctly.

Comment: Is this your full Typoscript? It should be under `page.includeCSS`. Also you missing `=` sign it should be `googlefontcssfile = https://fonts.googleapis...` not `googlefontcssfilehttps://fonts.googleapis...`

Comment: `preconnect` is not supported so far. So, you have to use headerData (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#headerdata-array)